# Conditioning on input variables and creating new variables in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("Check1",label=h4 ("Coin Type:"), choices = c("Fair","Unfair (p = 60% for heads)"))
))
```

**server.R**:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  if (input$Check1 == "Fair"){
    x <- 1
    output$Value <- renderTable(as.data.frame(x))
  } else { 
    x <- 5
    output$Value <- renderTable(as.data.frame(x))
  }
})
```

This should be very simple: there should be two check boxes. When "Fair" is checked, give `x` the value 1; otherwise, 5. Then display it on a data frame.

The problem, I think, is from assigning the variable `x`. Here is the error I get:

```
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    44: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    43: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    42: $.reactivevalues
    41: $ [-- this has a folder directory --]
    40: server [-- this has a folder directory --]
     1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

[note that I omitted `41` and `40` above].

How do I deal with this problem? Searching has led me to nothing, and it isn't clear to me how to use `reactiveValues`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make x reactive to do what you want like so:

```
x <- reactive({
  if (input$Check1 == "Fair"){
  1
} else { 
  5  
}
# pass reactive x() to renderTable
output$Value <- renderTable(as.data.frame(x()))
```